# I can not check in project

Tags: azure-devops

> TF400963: The supplied paths are considered identical by the database.
>   Please change one or both of them. The paths are:
>   $/SAA/ArNikAPI/02-Api/ArNikAPI/ArNikAPI.csproj and
>   $/SAA/ArNikAPI/02-Api/ArNikAPI/ArNikAPI.csproj.

Comment: Recreating your workspace could solve your problem.

Comment: Please also check if the workspace mapped correctly. Or you can optimize you workapsce by the following article and checkin again  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/optimize-your-workspace.